# Quickest way to spot resource allocation conflict

Tags: javascript, algorithm

We have an *order options* array of `n` child arrays. We want to know if we could get an *order fulfillment* array where:

1. Every order item gets one (any) of it's options,
2. *Order fulfillment* array consists of unique values

Some examples to visualize the problem:

```
[
  [3, 5],
  [3, 5]
]
result: true
possible order_fulfillment = [3,5]
----------------------------------
[
  [3, 5],
  [3, 5],
  [3, 5]
]
result: false
----------------------------------
[
  [3, 5],
  [3, 5],
  [3, 5, 6]
]
result: true
possible order_fulfillment = [3,5,6]
```

I am currently using a brute force approach, checking all possible combinations until I find a complete *order fulfillment* at which point I return true, or until I have inspected all possible combinations with no success and then return false.

I am interested to know if a better approach exists.
This would be executed in a browser, hence the javascript tag.

Answer (score 1):

So just iterate through each array of children, iterate the children, only add unique.

```
var OrderOptions = [[3,5],[3,5],[3,5,6]];
var PossibleFullFillment = {};
for( var a = 0; a < OrderOptions.length; a++ )
{
 var OrderItems = OrderOptions[a];
 for( var b = 0; b < OrderItems.length; b++ )
 {
  var current = "" + OrderItems[b].toString();
  PossibleFullFillment[current] = current;
 }
}
var FullFillment = [];
for( var possible in PossibleFullFillment )
{
 FullFillment.push(parseInt(possible));
}
FullFillment.sort();
console.log(FullFillment);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NtPwc/

Comment: Thanks. For `[[3,5],[3,5],[3,5]]`, this returns `[3,5]`. The `.length` of `OrderItems` could be compared to the `.length` of the result in this case, but I need to do more tests to be sure this could handle all possible variations in the input.

Comment: The logic is not correct test number 4 should return false, but returns true: http://jsbin.com/udehag/1/edit

Comment: @MajidFouladpour - In what sense? `FullFillment` has `[3,5,12,32]`. *Your* logic dictates that the return be the comparison of the length of `FullFillment` in comparison to being more than or equal to the number of items. Both of which in this case are 4 so it returns **true**.

Comment: With `[[3,5],[3,5],[3],[12, 32]]` we should assign `3` to the third order item, then the first and second ones are only left with `5`. So condition #1 and #2 could not be both met: 1. Every order item gets one (any) of *it's options*, 2. Order fulfillment array consists of *unique values*.